# Initializing properties of an Objective-C class in Swift results in unexpected values and types

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, interop

I'm trying to initialize an Objective C class in Swift but I'm getting very unexpected results. Properties are all strings and get set inline during initialization. When I try to use the new object, the properties are not what I set but seem to point to arbitrary values (I'm guessing they're just picking up whatever is in memory locations they're pointing to). Here is what I have:

MTUserInfo.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MTUserInfo : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, readonly, assign) NSString* firstName;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, assign) NSString* lastName;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, assign) NSString* userEmail;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, assign) NSString* userPhone;

- (instancetype)initWithFirstName:(NSString*)firstName
                         lastName:(NSString*)lastName
                        userEmail:(NSString*)userEmail
                        userPhone:(NSString*)userPhone;

@end
```

MTUserInfo.m

```
#import "MTUserInfo.h"

@implementation MTUserInfo

- (instancetype)initWithFirstName:(NSString *)firstName
                         lastName:(NSString *)lastName
                        userEmail:(NSString *)userEmail
                        userPhone:(NSString *)userPhone
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        _firstName = firstName;
        _lastName = lastName;
        _userEmail = userEmail;
        _userPhone = userPhone;
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

And my simple View controller in Swift:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var userInfo: MTUserInfo

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        userInfo = MTUserInfo(firstName: "Firstname",
                              lastName: "Lastname",
                              userEmail: "email@provider.com",
                              userPhone: "555-555-4433")

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        print("User info: ", self.userInfo.firstName)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

When I debug it, here's what I get:
[image]

Any ideas on what's going on or how to fix it? I'm at a loss here.

Btw, this is a simplified example. In my real app I have no control over the Objective-C classes, they're imported as a library.

Comment: I think your should be calling `super.init(coder: aDecoder)` before initializing `userInfo`. You can mark `userInfo` implicitly unwrapped `var userInfo: MTUserInfo` to deal with the error you'll receive.

Comment: Allen, thank you for the pointer. Unfortunately, it has no effect on the issue I'm getting. Event if I update it to a local variable, the properties still end up pointing to some arbitrary locations in memory.

Comment: The problem is that those properties are are assign, which means that ARC is not retaining them.

Comment: Does the library contain any non-arc code?

Comment: Using an IUO just to avoid a Swift initialization rule (subclass variables must be set up before calling super) sounds like a terrible idea.

Comment: @MK_Dev At what point are you inspecting these values?

Answer (score 2):

Change your properties... NSStrings cannot be `assign`.

Use either `copy`:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString* firstName;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString* lastName;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString* userEmail;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString* userPhone;
```

or `strong`:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly, strong) NSString* firstName;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, strong) NSString* lastName;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, strong) NSString* userEmail;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, strong) NSString* userPhone;
```